# Convert timestamp to another timezone in Python

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pytz, timestamp-with-timezone

I have a timestamp (`1596526195`) that is in GMT+2 (`2020-08-04 11:29:55`) and I would like to convert it to GMT-5, so it should be `2020-08-04 04:29:55`.

For now, my script is:

```py
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

time_zone = "Etc/GMT-5"
ts = 1596533395 
ts_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(ts)
print(ts_date)  # 2020-08-04 11:29:55+00:00
ts_date_converted = pytz.utc.localize(ts_date).astimezone(pytz.timezone(time_zone))
print(ts_date_converted)  # 2020-08-04 16:29:55+05:00
```

I see two problems:

1. By default python takes `ts` as GMT+0. How to tell python to read this `ts` as GMT+2 ? I don't want to convert it because in that case it would change the `ts_date`, no ? `ts_date`should be `2020-08-04 11:29:55+02:00`, not `2020-08-04 09:29:55+00:00`
2. Why I have a result in GMT+5 whereas I'm trying to convert in GMT-5 ? `ts_date_converted` should be `2020-08-04 04:29:55-05:00` I believe

Thanks

Comment: note that GMT-5 (2020-08-04 04:29:55 from your example) would be "Etc/GMT+5", kind of confusing naming there

Comment: ...and a sidenote concerning *By default python takes ts as GMT+0*: yes, but unless you provide `tz` (see my answer), you will receive a datetime object that is naive (no time zone) but represents **local time** (i.e. according to your OS time zone setting). This is different to other languages where the default is UTC - so another confuser there.

Comment: Ok, it's really really confusing that GMT-5 is ETC/GMT+5...

Answer (score 2):

`datetime.fromtimestamp` takes an argument `tz` which allows you to supply time zone information, see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp). Also, if you only work with UTC offsets, you don't need a third party library. You can simply construct a `timezone` from a `timedelta`:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta

ts = 1596533395 
dt_UTCplus2 = datetime.fromtimestamp(ts, tz=timezone(timedelta(hours=2)))
print(dt_UTCplus2)
# 2020-08-04 11:29:55+02:00

dt_UTCminus5 = dt_UTCplus2.astimezone(timezone(timedelta(hours=-5)))
print(dt_UTCminus5)
# 2020-08-04 04:29:55-05:00
```

If you work with time zones instead of UTC offsets, I'd suggest you use [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) (`pytz` will be deprecated with the release of Python 3.9) or [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) for Python 3.9+:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import tz

ts = 1596533395 
dt_UTCplus2 = datetime.fromtimestamp(ts, tz=tz.gettz("Etc/GMT-2"))
print(dt_UTCplus2)
# 2020-08-04 11:29:55+02:00

dt_UTCminus5 = dt_UTCplus2.astimezone(tz.gettz("Etc/GMT+5"))
print(dt_UTCminus5)
# 2020-08-04 04:29:55-05:00
```